# Pass Javascript link inside the URL address bar in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to ask how I can modify a link to execute a java script code:

I have 2 different pages one is using translation which is activated with flag icon button and his link is:

```
<a href="#" onClick="translate('fr', '{$site_code}'); translateSection('fr', '{$site_code}'); translatInclude('fr', '{$site_code}'); lang = 'fr';"></a>
```

So the case is I am coming from another website something like `website.php`, is there a way to place java script behavior in this link to open the translated page directly something like:

```
website.php?translation="javascript"
```

where the translation variable will open the java script link and eventually the translated page?

Comment: You need to write Javascript code that consumes the querystring.

Comment: When the page loads, your JavaScript code can examine the query string and perform any actions you need at that time.  The URL *itself* can't contain JavaScript code, but your *page* certainly can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it could be using a GET variable, so something like `website.php?translation=1` and `website.php?translation=2` and so on. Inside the PHP script you can get that value and then using a switch echo different javascripts depending on your need.

```
$js = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET,"translation",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));//not sure about how get reacts to ints, so add intval anyways for safety.
switch($js)
{
    case 1:
    {
        echo "<script>alert(1);</script>";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        echo "<script>alert(2);</script>";
        break;
    }
}
```

edit: fixed horrible mistake, I used POST instead of GET without noticing.

Comment: there were missing semicolons after the `echo`s, sorry, fixed now.

Comment: @JohnSiniger code works fine on my test page. Make sure you visit the page with one of the GET variables provided such as `?translation=1`